# Find substring from a array of patterns

Tags: bash, expansion

I have a file with extensions:

```
f1=f1.e1.e2.e3.sh.pl.cpp
```

I have an array containing a list of extensions:

```
exts=(sh pl py)
```

I want to remove the extensions in exts from the filename's. Is there a trick to do it, I'm thinking of something of this kind:

```
${f1%.${exts[@]}}
```

It obviously does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I would construct a pattern from your `exts` array and then use `sed` :

```
f1=f1.e1.e2.e3.sh.pl.cpp
exts=(sh pl py)


function array_to_regex_alts() { # joins the array elements by \|
    echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "\|%s" "$@"
}

pattern="\.\($(array_to_regex_alts ${exts[@]} )\)"

echo $f1 | sed "s/$pattern//g"
```